# ubuntu studio 20.04 shows network connection but all apps show no internet connection

Tags: networking, internet

After installing a security update, my machine connects to the internet, but every app I run tells me I'm not connected. If I click the network icon and choose "connection information" I get the usual information, plus a tab labeled "pvpn-ipv6leak-protection" that I never saw before. This is the same via wifi or ethernet. When I click on the new tab, it lists my interface as "ivp6leakintrf0", shows a hardware address, shows the driver as "dummy" and speed as "unknown"

Pinging a website results in "Temporary failure in name resolution"

I did connect to Proton VPN once and it seemed to work fine. I didn't try to add it to either my wifi or ethernet connection profile.

Comment: Are you using some kind of vpn?

Comment: No.. I did connect to Proton VPN once and it seemed to work fine. I didn't try to add it to either my wifi or ethernet connection profile

Comment: what output is shown for `ping google.com` or any other website?

Comment: Temporary failurre in name resolution

Comment: Please add any additional nfo to your question and not in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Its fairly likely your VPN added a default route which hasnt gone away, or added a new DNS server for you. It would help to add the output of these to your question:

```
ip route show
```

and

```
systemd-resolve status
```